# PS cmdlet : Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext connect to Azure China

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure

I have a working script via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-keys-using-powershell (KeyVault + SQL Azure setup), in "Step 6. Authenticate to Azure, if your column master key is stored in Azure Key Vault.", I run PS "Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive", but this will pop a dialog connect to Azure US,not Azure CN.

I browsed cmdlet doc, cannot see anything setting environment parameter, how can I let the cmdlet connect to AzureCN?

Thanks,
Cheng

Comment: Do you mean you connect to Azure china via Powershell, then run this command still pop a dialog connect to Azure US?

Comment: yes, exactly. And Azure CN host provider responsed me, they are redirecting this issue to Microsoft, I can do nothing except wait.